# Problema al salvar en juego de snake

Tags: c++

Hola soy nuevo en esto de c++ y estaba haciendo un juego sencillo de serpiente 
Ya lo tengo casi todo completo el unico problema esque quiero hacer que cuando pierda salve las puntuaciones y los nombres el arhivo ya se crea pero cuando el juego arranca la funcion de salvar arranca y no deja jugar

esta es las funciones y el main para no poner tanto codigo:

```
bool record(){
string playerName; 
char option;
string display;

std::ofstream myfile("snake.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

system("cls");


cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: "<<endl;
cin>>playerName;

myfile<<playerName<<" "<<puntos<<endl;

myfile.close();

do{


cout<<"Quieres ver los records pasados? (y/n)"<<endl;
cin>>option;

switch(option){
    case 'y':
        ifstream myfile ("snake.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open()){
            system("cls");

            while ( getline (myfile,display) ){

                  cout << display << '\n';
            }
            system("pause");
            myfile.close();
        }
    break;  
}
}while(option != 'n');

}

bool game_over()
{
 if(y == 3 || y == 23 || x == 2 || x == 77)
 return false;
 for(int j = tam - 1; j > 0; j--){
         if(cuerpo[j][0] == x &&  cuerpo[j][1] == y){
         return false;
         }
 }
 if(y != 3 || y != 23 || x != 2 || x != 77){
    record();
 }
 return true;         
 }
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
OcultaCursor();

pintar();
gotoxy(xc, yc); printf("%c", 4);

while(tecla != ESC && game_over())
{
     borrar_cuerpo();
     guardar_posicion();
     dibujar_cuerpo();
     comida();
     teclear();
     teclear();


     if(dir == 1) y--;
     if(dir == 2) y++;
     if(dir == 3) x++;
     if(dir == 4) x--;

     Sleep(velocidad);
}

cout<<puntos<<endl;
    if(game_over()){
    record();
}

pintar();
return 0;
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Gracias

Comment: `dir` empieza con 3 `x` empieza con 10 `y` empieza con 12

Answer (score 4):

¿ Valores `x`, `y`, y `dir` en los que inicias el juego ?

Tú haces

```
if (y == 3 || y == 23 || x == 2 || x == 77)
    return false;

...

if (y != 3 || y != 23 || x != 2 || x != 77) {
    record();
}
```

Salvo que inicies en `x == 2 || x == 77` o `y == 3 || y == 23`, entrarás en el segundo `if( )`, con lo que guardaras. Después de guardar, continuas el `while( )`, con lo que vuelves a llamar a `game_over( )`. Donde vuelves a comprobar, y puedes seguir en ese bucle eternamente. Depende de cómo inicies `x`, `y` y `dir`.

**EDITO**

Según los nuevos datos, repetirás el bucle de guardado eternamente.

Al iniciar el juego, en cada llamada a `game_over( )`, `y != 23` se cumple **siempre**. En el bucle principal, haces

```
 if(dir == 3) x++;
```

cambias el valor de `x`, pero `y` sigue igual.

Deberías de examinar la lógica interna de `game_over( )`. No obstante, puesto que dices que funciona, una posible solución es utilizar una variable auxiliar.

Por ejemplo `int started = 0`. La pones a `1` en el `main( )`, dentro del `while( )`. Y cambias el segundo `if( )` dentro de `game_over( )`.

```
if( started && ( y != 3 || y != 23 || x != 2 || x != 77 ) )
  record();

return true;
```

Con esos cambios, debería funcionar.